# After I select a Multi-level List, why must I click on “Numbering” to apply that List to subsequent paragraphs?

Tags: discussion

Why did Mokubai unilaterally close

[After I select a Multi-level List, why must I click on "Numbering" to apply that List to subsequent paragraphs?](https://superuser.com/q/1540916/926483) (why Word highlights "Numbering" and not "Multi-level List")

as a duplicate of

[After I select a Multi-level List, why can't Word apply that List to subsequent paragraphs?](https://superuser.com/q/1540918/926483) (why Word can't apply either to an un-numbered paragraphs)?

Doubtless they are not duplicates. In the first, Word applies a numbered list to text, but the wrong one. You get a numbered list in the end.

In the second, Word isn't applying any numbered list. You get no numbered list in the end.

Comment: They certainly appear to be duplicates of one another to me.

Comment: Rather than ask why it was closed, and stating they're not dupes - why not explain why they're not dupes instead?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I did explain why they're not dupes? I'll write more.

Answer (score 2):

They closed it because one of the questions is "Why can't I do `thing`?" and the other is "Why do I have to click `something` to do `thing`?"

It appears there there is a problem in one that is already assumed to be fixed, or is fixed by, by the other.

If you want you can edit your question to clarify why they are distinct and separate, or I can reverse the duplicate direction.

Comment: is it clear now?